# Add Sequential Numbers To Data

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table named tblFriends:

[image]

tblFriends is generated from query qryFriends. The data and number of records within tblFriends changes everyday but is never more than 30.

I would like to generate sequential numbers next to each of the Names, but this seems to be extremely difficult.

If you assume table tblSEQLikes has already been made with fields (SEQ, Likes).

This is the code that I have been trying to use:

```
Dim rs As Recordset

Dim strLikes As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryFriends", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblSEQLikes (SEQ, Likes) VALUES (" & SEQNum & ", '" & strLikes & "')"

For SEQNum = 1 To 30

    strDisc = rs.Fields("Likes").Value

        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    rs.MoveNext

Next SEQNum
```

I continue to get error stating, "Run-time error '3219' Invalid operation"

This code is a modification of the code used in this youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNm17l54z1c

The result, I feel like this should give in tblSEQLikes is as follows:

SEQ Likes

1   Bikes

2   Food

3   Money

4   Shoes

5   Computers

6   Clothes

7   Soda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strLikes` is never used. Also, move `strSQL` assignment in loop after getting value of `strLikes` (assuming `strDisc` should be `strLikes`)

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryFriends", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

For SEQNum = 1 To 30

    Dim likes As String
    likes = rs.Fields("Likes").Value

    Dim sql as String
    sql = "INSERT INTO tblSEQLikes (SEQ, Likes) VALUES (" & SEQNum & ", '" & likes & "')"

        DoCmd.RunSQL sql

    rs.MoveNext

Next SEQNum
```

*i removed the hungarian notation (strLikes)*

Comment: That solved it! Thanks!! Just curious, I'm new at coding...why does the strSQL need to be in the loop?

Comment: @reickmey - because the loop defines both the value of `SEQNum` and `likes`. Before the loop these values are never set so you would be passing null values. I just noticed, to be safe, add `rs.MoveFirst` as the first statement after `Set rs = ...`. This will ensure you pick up all the records you want.